# Backup software that supports differential backup or syncing? (rsync interface maybe?) W7

Tags: backup, windows-backup, windows-7-backup, incremental-backup

I am looking for an incremental / differential / sync backup utility that does not require a full backup to begin.

I have a TB external drive with backups of pictures and movies, about 800GB, and I backed it up a few months ago at around 750GB. I don't want to write all 800GB again if possible (takes too long). There must be software that only writes the data that has changed, sort of like a Drop Box sync?

I found rsync, but I would prefer something that is more user friendly (start program and run backup task). Or if someone can advise on how to make rsync easier, that would be great as well.

Comment: In Super User, and all the StackExchange sites, shopping or product recommendations are considered off topic and open ended, and sometimes even too localized. Try to reword your question in a way that you are not asking for products, but more of processes; this will help keep it on topic

Answer (score 2):

If only copying the files then you could look at Robocopy, it's built in to Win7, it will only copy files that are new or changed.

Or you could look at [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) if you want rsync

Comment: Awesome Deltacopy looks good, but I just found SyncBack which is working great. Much better than Cobian which requires a full backup to start working differentially.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable software is SyncBack.

I am not sure that it does piecewise syncing of files like Rsync (replace only the changed bits of a file), but it does differential syncing without a first initial backup.

I recommend the software. The free version of SyncBack suits my needs.